# How to display oData content in welcome pop up

Tags: javascript, html, odata, sapui5

How to show data in html tag from oData service. It is UI plugin.

Please find fragment code given below. I have to show data in this area where manual entry is done on the basis of some conditions. If you have any other idea then do share. Please find my project in the [Git URL - zwelcomepopup](https://github.com/rkmishra2703/RK-)

***Welcome to GW system press close button to start your activity.***

```
<VBox>
    <html:div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 32px 16px 0 16px; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; font-family: Arial, Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; min-height: 296px;">
        <html:h1 style="color: #007cc0; font-size: 25px; padding-bottom: 16px; border-bottom: solid #cdcdcd 4px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0;">
            Whats New</html:h1>
        <html:p style="color: #666; line-height: 20px; margin-bottom: 0; font-size: 16px;">
            ***Welcome to GWX system press close button to start your activity.***
        </html:p>
    </html:div>
</VBox>
```

Comment: It's not supporting in SCP. Please check and import in your WEB Ide.

Answer (score 0):

You can open a SAPUI5 - Dialog with your OData Content in you component.js:

```
   sap.ui.define(["sap/m/Dialog"], function(Dialog) {

    return Component.extend("my.Launchpad.plugin.Component", {
        init: function() {

            //Read Data...

            var sWelcomeText = this.oModel.getProperty("/WelcomeText"); //Get the OData Content
            var oDialog = new Dialog("myDialog", {
                title: "Whats New",
                content: [
                    new sap.m.Text({
                        text: sWelcomeText
                    }).addStyleClass("sapUiSmallMargin")
                ],
                buttons: [
                    new sap.m.Button({
                        text: "Close",
                        press: function () {
                            oDialog.close();
                        }
                    })
                ]
            });
            oDialog.open();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks alexP for your suggestion. I have requirement like. I have to show certain description for example in case of browser selected language ex : EN then it should compare show English description and for ES , ES description. I have table in that ID, EN, EN Description, ES, ES description are stored. How will I access or pass ID  for example want to access EN or EN description I can use below approach  : var browserLang = oModel.getProperty("/EmpLangSet('" + ID + "')/zlangen");  but how to store ID here. If you can suggest that will be helpful.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further details  Language access API : sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getUser().getLanguage()....I will compare this and show the description accordingly